# Copy query output data from SQL SERVER 2012 and paste to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, copy-paste

I have a column that has data type varchar(max). Some rows in that column have long text data. When I copy the SQL result set from that column and paste to excel, the row gets split into multiple rows. I want to past in sunch a way that single cell data from SQL server go to
single cell in excel. I am not sure how to fix that problem. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you copy/pasting from SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy And Paste From SQL Server Management Studio 2012 New Line Issue Into Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380779/copy-and-paste-from-sql-server-management-studio-2012-new-line-issue-into-excel)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Excel Import from SQL Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx) feature.  It should import each row of data into a single row in Excel and each column into a single column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select data directly into excel spreadsheet.

Check this for more details 
http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/code-library/ad-hoc-querying/#codesyntax_5