# How can I fix this regex expression?

Tags: c#, regex, csv, parsing

Preface: This question is a derivative of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59761275/109941).

---

[Here is my code](https://repl.it/repls/AvariciousMindlessEllipse):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
        const string rawLine = "\"TeamName\",\"PlayerName\",\"Position\"  \"Chargers\",\"Philip Rivers\",\"QB\"  \"Colts\",\"Peyton Manning\",\"QB\"  \"Patriots\",\"Tom Brady\",\"QB\"";
        var parsedLines = Regex.Split(rawLine, "(\".*? \"(?:,\".*? \")*)");
        parsedLines.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
"TeamName","PlayerName","Position"  "
Chargers
","Philip Rivers","QB"  "
Colts
","Peyton Manning","QB"  "
Patriots","Tom Brady","QB"
Press [ENTER] to exit.
```

And here is my desired output:

```
"TeamName","PlayerName","Position"
"Chargers","Philip Rivers","QB"
"Colts","Peyton Manning","QB"
"Patriots","Tom Brady","QB"
Press [ENTER] to exit.
```

How can I fix the regex to generate my desired output?

---

Relevant:

- [line breaks lost in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8387976/109941)
- [How do you view ALL text from an ntext or nvarchar(max) in SSMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11897950/109941)

Comment: I strongly recommend using CSVHelper instead of regex for this unless you're sure the CSV won't contain things like embedded/escaped quotes or commas.  CSV is a *very* flexible format.  It doesn't even have to be comma-separated to qualify as a CSV.

Comment: @Amy I'm not familiar with CSVHelper, but I'm all ears. Can you please describe a solution with CSVHelper?

Comment: It has been a long while since I've had need of its services (no CSVs in the past couple of years :o ), but I remember their documentation was fairly good.  See https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started.

Comment: You could just split on `"\"  \""` and put the leading and trailing double quotes back on each result.

Comment: Or maybe even do a replace of `"\"  \""` with `"\"\n\""` or whatever newline characters you desire.

Comment: Unless CSVHelper has a way to specify the *record* delimiter, it's not going to be of any help. An answer (since deleted) on the previous question mentioned the `Delimiter` property of CSVHelper's configuration but that's the *field* delimiter (and that's why it was deleted). I was unable to find a record delimiter option (but that doesn't mean there isn't one). The other answer there mentions splitting, both on two spaces and on quote-space-space-quote, so one would hope that was already explored before turning to regex and then posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind, positive lookbehind, character class with quanitifer, positive lookahead, and negative lookahead.

[Working Demo](https://repl.it/repls/VitalCalculatingSystem)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
        const string rawLine = "\"TeamName\",\"PlayerName\",\"Position\"  \"Chargers\",\"Philip Rivers\",\"QB\"  \"Colts\",\"Peyton Manning\",\"QB\"  \"Patriots\",\"Tom Brady\",\"QB\"";
            var parsedLines = Regex.Split(rawLine, "(?<![,])(?<=[\"])[ ]{2}(?=[\"])(?![,])");
            parsedLines.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Amy has already mentioned, your string seems to be something like CSV. If it is really a valid CSV - use special libraries.

If CSVHelper isn't applicable in this case and you really need regex, try something like this one:

```
(?<=(?:^|  ))(.*?)(?=(?:  \")|$)
```

I haven't coded for C#, so regex may need some edits due to c# specific.

*Edit. Code example.*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
        const string rawLine = "\"TeamName\",\"PlayerName\",\"Position\"  \"Chargers\",\"Philip Rivers\",\"QB\"  \"Colts\",\"Peyton Manning\",\"QB\"  \"Patriots\",\"Tom Brady\",\"QB\"";
            //var parsedLines = Regex.Split(rawLine, "(?<=(?:^|  ))(.*?)(?=(?:  \")|$)");
      var parsedLines = Regex.Split(rawLine, "(?<=^)(.*?)(?=(?:  \")|$)|(?<=  )(.*?)(?=(?:  \")|$)");
            parsedLines.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

This code with "dirty" fix for assertion error. However, i can't reproduce it with onlinetool :)
Original regex commented in this example.

I hope, this will help you. But i must say again if you working with csv - it is better to use special tools, not regex :)

Comment: You can use dotnetfiddle or regexstorm for testing regex in c#.

Comment: Ouch, thanks. I missed that i can test on repl.it link, that you provided. Regex her seemd to be good. But if C# gets asserion error - we can try "dirty" fix. I'll edit my post right now.

Answer (score 0):

Good comments through-out the thread (I would strongly suggest pursuing one of those options), I wont focus on them. Here's an alternative solution that uses `Matches` from the `Regex` pattern, `skip` how many fields you have (columns) and then `take` how many records you want.

I'm using a pattern like `(\"(.*?)[^,]")` and explanation can be found [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/hvRmDG/1) of what it means.

```
const string rawLine = "\"TeamName\",\"PlayerName\",\"Position\"  \"Chargers\",\"Philip Rivers\",\"QB\"  \"Colts\",\"Peyton Manning\",\"QB\"  \"Patriots\",\"Tom Brady\",\"QB\"";                       
var matches = new Regex(@"(\""(.*?)[^,]"")").Matches(rawLine).Cast<Match>().ToList();
// loop through our matches
for(int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{                
    // join our records we need to output
    string str = string.Join(",", matches.Skip(i * 3).Take(3));
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
         Console.WriteLine(str);
}            
Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Please note, there's no error checking at all, can be improved, but does produces the output you need. *Also make sure you import `System.Linq` if not already there.

**Output Test**

[image]